# Getting Django function to return and render HTML page

Tags: python, django

I have function (inside a [class](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#classes)) that returns `True` if a user [is_authenticate()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_authenticated) and [is_active](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_active) but it is not returning **HTML** as I thought it would.

```
class LoginDetails:
    def __init__(self, request):
        self.request = request
        self.template = 'myapp/errorpage.html'
        self.context = {}

    def user_is_logged_in(self):
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated() and self.request.user.is_active:
            print 'USER IS AUTHENTICATED!'
            return True
        print 'USER IS NOT AUTHENTICATED!'
        return render(self.request, self.template, self.context)
```

**views.py**:

```
def authUsers(request):
    logindetails = LoginDetails(request).user_is_logged_in()
    return HttpResponse("HTML Error Page Not Rendered")
```

How do I get the function to display/render error page without me doing it in *views.py*? Example of what I want to achieve is Stackoverflow's [Page Not Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/397288888888888882033/android-retrotfit-modify-fields-of-object-after-receive).

Comment: You shouldn't use "page not found" here; authentication failure is a 401, not a 404.

Comment: returning `render` from a method called `user_is_logged_in` doesn't make any sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your class really is redundant, calling it takes one line and modifying your view is also one line

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, Http404

def authUsers(request):
   if request.user.is_authenticated() and request.user.is_active:
       raise Http404
   else :
       return render(...)
```

Using that class merely complicates matters. But if you really wanted to, you could modify it like this:

```
class LoginDetails:
    def __init__(self, request):
        self.request = request
        self.template = 'myapp/errorpage.html'
        self.context = {}

    def user_is_logged_in(self):
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated() and self.request.user.is_active:
            return False

        return render(self.request, self.template, self.context)


def authUsers(request):
    logindetails = LoginDetails(request).user_is_logged_in()
    if not logindetails:
        return HttpResponse("HTML Error Page Not Rendered")
    else:
        return logindetails
```